# formal definition of a sequence limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to prove that the limit of a sequence sqrt(a_n)=sqrt(L), where I'm given that the sequence a_n converges to the limit L. We are given L>=0 as well. So far I have rearranged abs(sqrt(a_n)-sqrt(L))M for some random M. and abs(sqrt(a_n-L)

Comment: The square root function is continuous, so it preserves sequences.

Comment: if you want the $\varepsilon\ -\ N$ approach, maybe you need $\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{L} = \dfrac{a_n - L}{\sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{L}}$

Comment: Yes, I did something along those lines. I'm unfamiliar with the episolon - N approach, what's that? Is it something along the lines of episolon - N >= 0 or something?

Comment: The $\epsilon, N$ definition of a limit of a sequence of real numbers (or of an sort of things in a space where distances can be defined) is a lot like the $\epsilon, \delta$ definition of the limit of a function.  To wit, $L$ is the limit of sequence $\left\{ s_n \right\}$ iff for any given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $N$ (which value might depend on the chosen $\epsilon$) such that for all $n>N$, $|L-s_n|< \epsilon$.

Comment: Yes I know this proof, however I don't know which N to choose given that I solved my episolon equation. I don't know how to related a_n to n, therefore I don't really know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

Since $f(x)=x^{\frac12}$ is continuous, and $a_n \to L$ as $n\to \infty$, then we can conclude that $a_n^{\frac12} \to L^{\frac12}$ as $n\to \infty$.

Another way ($\epsilon-N$):

Since $a_n \to L$ as $n\to \infty$, then for any $\epsilon$, there exists $N>0$, such that when $n>N$, $|a_n-L| < 2\sqrt{L}\epsilon$, and hence $a_n=|a_n|<2\sqrt{L}\epsilon+|L|= 2\sqrt{L}\epsilon+ L$.

Now consider $$|\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{L}|=\frac{|a_n-L|}{\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{L}}<\frac{2\sqrt{L}\epsilon}{2\sqrt{L}}=\epsilon.$$